# Rock Paper Scissors IIF but IIF is not changing the values of the const named outcome

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to get a rock paper scissors game to work using the ternary operator in vb.net, but no matter how I set it up, I get the wrong results(continues to output the same outcome, no matter what the actual outcome should be I.E, R vs P = lose, R vs S = lose, R vs R = lose)

I had originally tried using outcome/draw bool as a placeholder with an if at the end to display the outcome, and added an exit switch inside the ifs immediately following the IIF but still it would result in a loop of not changing the outcome.

```
Public Class Form1
    Const ROCK As Integer = 1
    Const PAPER As Integer = 2
    Const SCISSORS As Integer = 3
    Dim computerThrow As Integer
    Dim comThrow As String = "Rock"
    Dim wins As Integer
    Dim losses As Integer
    Dim draws As Integer
    Dim outcome As Boolean = True
    Dim draw As Boolean = True

    'Spent two days debugging, kept getting more broken. hmm
    Private Sub btnThrow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnThrow.Click

        'Generate computer throw
        Randomize()
        computerThrow = Int(3 * Rnd() + 1)

        'Select case block
        Select Case computerThrow
            Case ROCK
                comThrow = "rock"
                IIf(Me.radRock.Checked = True, draw = True, 1 = 1) 'Ternarys to decide outcome/draw
                If draw = True Then 'If to decide whether to exit or not
                    Me.lblWinner.Text = "Computer throws " + comThrow + ", it's a draw!"
                    draws = draws + 1
                End If
                IIf(Me.radPaper.Checked = True, outcome = True, 1 = 1)
                If outcome = True Then
                    Me.lblWinner.Text = "Computer throws " + comThrow + ", you win!"
                    wins = wins + 1
                End If
                IIf(Me.radScissors.Checked = True, outcome = False, 1 = 1)
                If outcome = False And draw = False Then
                    Me.lblWinner.Text = "Computer throws " + comThrow + ", you lose!"
                    losses = losses + 1
                End If
            Case PAPER
                comThrow = "paper"
                IIf(Me.radRock.Checked = True, outcome = False, 1 = 1)
                If outcome = False And draw = False Then
                    Me.lblWinner.Text = "Computer throws " + comThrow + ", you lose!"
                    losses = losses + 1
                End If
                IIf(Me.radPaper.Checked = True, draw = True, 1 = 1)
                If draw = True Then
                    Me.lblWinner.Text = "Computer throws " + comThrow + ", it's a draw!"
                    draws = draws + 1
                End If
                IIf(Me.radScissors.Checked = True, outcome = True, 1 = 1)
                If outcome = True Then
                    Me.lblWinner.Text = "Computer throws " + comThrow + ", you win!"
                    wins = wins + 1
                End If
            Case SCISSORS
                comThrow = "scissors"
                IIf(Me.radRock.Checked = True, outcome = True, 1 = 1)
                If outcome = True Then
                    Me.lblWinner.Text = "Computer throws " + comThrow + ", you win!"
                    wins = wins + 1
                End If
                IIf(Me.radPaper.Checked = True, outcome = False, 1 = 1)
                If outcome = False And draw = False Then
                    Me.lblWinner.Text = "Computer throws " + comThrow + ", you lose!"
                    losses = losses + 1
                End If
                IIf(Me.radScissors.Checked = True, draw = True, 1 = 1)
                If draw = True Then
                    Me.lblWinner.Text = "Computer throws " + comThrow + ", it's a draw!"
                    draws = draws + 1
                End If
        End Select

        Me.lblResults.Text = "wins: " + wins.ToString() + " Lose: " + losses.ToString() + " draws: " + draws.ToString()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Check [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx), I don't think it does what you think it is. IIf isn't meant to set a variable but to return a variable. Right now, you aren't using the returned value of IIf anywhere.

Comment: @the_lotus I tried to set lblWinner.Text inside the IIF, would that not work? It told me it was expecting an expression?

Comment: @Zen72901 it would not, it would do a comparison instead of setting the value.

Answer (score 5):

IIF is not the ternary operator in VB.NET. [IIF is a function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx) and both the true part and the false part are evaluated. This means that, whatever is the checked state of your checkboxes, the true part of the IIF function is always executed, thus you always get the variable assigned to true or false.

On the contrary the [conditional ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator) in VB.NET is **If(expression, true part,false part)**, which uses [shortcircuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to choose the expression value.
Thus you should rewrite your code in this way

```
  draw = If(Me.radRock.Checked, True, False)
  If draw Then 
     ....
```

But at this point you could simply write

```
  draw = Me.radRock.Checked
  If draw Then 
     ....
```

or

```
  outcome = Not Me.radRock.Checked
  ....
```